# Can zip4j be used to extract Tar files?

Tags: java, tar, unzip, zip4j

In an application we use the zip4j library to decompress zip files.

```
File toBeExtractedFile = new File("valid/path/to/File");
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(toBeExtractedFile);
zipFile.setFileNameCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name);
zipFile.extractAll("valid/path")
```

With .zip files this code works perfectly fine. But when done with a .tar file, this wil throw a `new ZipException("zip headers not found. probably not a zip file");` 
Can the zip4j library extract TAR files when given additional info or parameters or do i have to resort to using something else like a `TarArchiveInputstream`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, ZIP and TAR are two different archive formats. You can use [Apache Commons Compress](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/tar.html) which supports TAR format.